# TDD, Matrix Additions Not Working

Tags: java, matrix, tdd

Lowdown: Beginning Java course. Lecture has been about collections, and nothing really too difficult in concept. All theory, not blood and guts coding.

Lab, has been a series of coding projects completely unrelated to the lecture (or mostly anyway).

This lab is about Test Driven Development. The Exact text is as such:

Write tests for, and an implementation of, a method which performs matrix
addition on integer matrices, as described below.  Note that "x" and "y" must
have the same dimensions; the resulting matrix will also have the same
dimensions.

```
public int[][] add(int[][] x, int[][] y);
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html for
documentation about arrays.

Challenge - write the tests BEFORE you write implementation code.  Make sure
you have a good understanding of what the properties of matrix addition are
before you attempt to write code to perform it.

For more information about matrix addition, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixAddition.html
and the references cited there.  Note the two properties of matrix addition:
commutativity and associativity --- you tests should verify these properties.

**My Test Code First Attempt**

```
package tests;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import code.Homework4Practice;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ReferenceTests 
{

    private code.Homework4Practice _class;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        _class = new code.Homework4Practice();
    }


    @Test 
    public void addMatrice01()
    {
        int [][] a = {{1,2}, {1,0}};
        int [][] b = {{1,0}, {1,2}};
        int [][] expected = {{2,2}, {2,2}};
        int [][] actual = _class.addMatrices(a, b);
        assertTrue("Calling addMatrices with arguments \""+a+"\" and \""+b+"\" I expected the result to be {2,2} {2,2} but instead the result was " +arrayEquals(expected,actual));
    }

    private boolean arrayEquals(int[][] expected, int[][] actual) {
        if (expected.length != actual.length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<expected.length; i++) {
            if (expected[i] != actual[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Clearly I am having an issue with the assertTrue line.

Now, I know I was in trouble because I had to actually write the code (and look it up) for matrix addition, I knew how to do it from other classes, but I couldn't code it properly at first. So this is what the code looks like I am trying to develop tests for:

**My Code to Test**

```
package code;

public class Homework4Practice 
{
    public int[][] addMatrices (int[][] a, int[][]b)
    {   
        int[][] answer = new int[a.length][a[0].length];

        for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < a.length; col++ )
            {
                answer[row][col] = a[row][col] + b[row][col];
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

}
```

And with that I have no idea how to really go about doing this. It seems like there are plenty of resources online about TDD but I am not really sure how to apply it here. Time is crunching down on me and I just can't seem to get assistance anywhere else.

I completely understand and appreciate the importance of TDD, but it clearly escapes me in implementation.

Thanks for any help folks.

Comment: I'm confused; are you asking how you would write tests without knowing what the code does?

Comment: I think you simply want a comma in your assertTrue() call.  Not `assertTrue("blah" + arrayEquals(blah))` but instead `assertTrue("blah", arrayEquals(blah))`

Comment: @Jason Baker: In a nut shell I guess so, or at least some helpful nudgings.

Comment: @CarlManaster that took care of the error on the assertTrue line, thanks, but my tests still fail.

Comment: So what error is printed out?

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: Calling addMatrices with arguments "[[I@817b38" and "[[I@4437c4" I expected the result to be {2,2} {2,2} but instead the result was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that Java won't print out arrays prettily by default, so you need to write an `arrayPrint` method.

Then you can change your `assertTrue` to the following:

```
`assertTrue("Expected {{2,2},{2,2}}, got " + arrayPrint(actual), arrayEquals(expected, actual));
```

If you're failing that assert, it's because either your `addMatrices` or `arrayEquals` are not doing what you expect. The assert message should tell you which, and then you can debug.

As to how to go about doing TDD, in theory you should treat your (unwritten) function as a black box: stuff goes in, and stuff comes out, and you don't care how that transformation happens. Then you can write some tests for what you *expect* will come out of the box for certain inputs. In your matrix addition example, the following would be a perfectly reasonable TDD test case:

```
Assert addMatrices({{1,2},{1,0}}, {{1,0},{1,2}}) == {{2,2},{2,2}}
```

In other words, your test case is perfectly acceptable TDD, *as long as you didn't know how `addMatrices` worked when you wrote it*. In theory you can use this suite of tests to guide your development; if you're failing tests, you should be able to get an idea of why from the output of those failed tests.

One of the big problems I've had with this in practice is that, if you don't know what the function is supposed to do (For example, if you didn't know what matrix addition does), it can be hard to write tests for that function. If that happens to you, I don't have any good advice beyond do exactly what you did.